# Programatically Create Treemap chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

The Excel ChartType enum in Office Interop version 15 doesn't include a value for Treemap charts as well as a few others. If the Treemap was included, it would have a value of 117 (if my memory serves me). So I figured I could change the the type of a chart by simply applying this value to the Chart.ChartType property in code. However, I get an error that it is an invalid value. Does anyone know how to get around this? Essentially I want to take an existing Chart object and change it to a Treemap chart. This works with most chart types buy not the Treemap.

Comment: Can you do it manually? If so, try recording a macro and posting code here if you can't modify it yourself

Comment: What Excel version ?

Comment: I'm using Office 2016.

Comment: If I create macros, it shows the action that changes the chart type when I change it to a type such as Area. But if I change it to Treemap, it doesn't show the action, it only shows the chart being activated.